# 400 (Bad Request) ao enviar array para Spring Controller usando AJAX

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring

> POST http://localhost:7001/app/workflow/execute/ 400 (Bad Request)

Estou obtendo esse erro ao tentar enviar 2 array's para o meu controller Spring, porém estou obtendo esse erro, tentei algumas soluções que encontrei no SOen porém não obtive sucesso. A versão do meu Spring é a 3.0.2.

**Código JS**

```
var url = '/app/workflow/execute/';
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        processName : pName,
        argumentsNameArray : argumentsNameArr,
        argumentsValArray : argumentsValArr
    },
})
.done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

**Código java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/workflow/execute/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public WorkflowProcess executeWFProccess(
        @PathVariable("processName") String processName,
        @PathVariable("argumentsNameArray[]") String[] argumentsNameArray,
        @PathVariable("argumentsValArray[]") String[] argumentsValArray) {

    WorkflowProcess wfProcess = new WorkflowProcess();
    ArrayList<WFArgument> wfArguments = new ArrayList<WFArgument>();
    wfProcess.setProcessName(processName);

    for (int i = 0; i < argumentsNameArray.length; i++) {
        wfArguments.add( new WFArgument(argumentsNameArray[i], argumentsValArray[i]) );
    }
    wfProcess.setArguments(wfArguments);

    return wfProcess;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro temos que entender como a requisição é feita, como os valores chegarão no servidor. Para isto basta vermos na documentação do jQuery e teremos por lá que o `data` do [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) é enviado como parâmetros da URL.

A segunda coisa a entender é a diferença de `@PathVaviable` e `@RequestParam`, ou seja, quando cada uma deve ser usada. Pela documentação podemos perceber que [`@PathVaviable`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates) é usado para recuperar valores de variáveis em *URI templates*, como por exemplo `/workflow/execute/{processName}`, então teríamos algo assim:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/workflow/execute/{processName}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public WorkflowProcess executeWFProccess(@PathVaviable("processName") final String processName) {
    // faz alguma coisa
}
```

Como vimos no início a sua requisição coloca os valores como parâmetros e não como variáveis na URL. Então, quando estamos usando parâmetros temos que usar [`@RequestParam`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestparam) para que o Spring consiga mapear os parâmetros da requisição para as variáveis do nosso *request mapping*.

Considerando isto, precisamos apenas alterar de `@PathVaviable` para `@RequestParam` no seu exemplo, ficando assim:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/app")
public class WorkflowProcessWS {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/workflow/execute/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public WorkflowProcess executeWFProccess(@RequestParam("processName") final String processName,
            @RequestParam("argumentsNameArray[]") final String[] argumentsNameArray,
            @RequestParam("argumentsValArray[]") final String[] argumentsValArray) {
        final WorkflowProcess process = new WorkflowProcess();
        final List<WFArgument> wfArguments = new ArrayList<>();
        process.setProcessName(processName);
        for (int i = 0; i < argumentsNameArray.length; i++) {
            wfArguments.add(new WFArgument(argumentsNameArray[i], argumentsValArray[i]));
        }
        process.setArguments(wfArguments);
        return process;
    }

}
```

Apenas para testar fiz uma chamada desta forma:

```
var url = '/app/workflow/execute/';
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    type : 'POST',
    dataType : 'json',
    data : {
        processName : "Nome do Processo",
        argumentsNameArray : ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3"],
        argumentsValArray : ["Val1", "Val2", "Val3"]
    },
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log("processName: " + data.processName);
    $.each(data.arguments, function(key, value) {
        console.log("key: " + key + " | value: " + value.val + " | name: " + value.name);
    });
});
```

E o retorno logou isto(apenas uma parte, para ficar menor aqui) no console do chrome:

[image: Resultado da requisição]

Por fim, caso seja necessário, você pode recuperar todos os parâmetros da requisição mapeando-os para um [MultiValueMap](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/MultiValueMap.html), incluindo algo como isto no seu método:

```
@RequestParam final MultiValueMap<String, String> params
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, @Bruno César! Utilizando o `@RequestParam` funcionou corretamente.

Answer (score 0):

De onde vem argumentsNameArr e argumentsValArray na parte do Javascript?

Eles precisam estar em um formato do tipo `variavel[]=valor1`, `variavel[]=valor2`
para serem interpretados pelo Java como um Array

Tente também usar

```
    @PathVariable("argumentsNameArray") String[] argumentsNameArray // repare na ausencia dos []
```

Comment: Eu monto as array iterando os campos do meu form: `$('input[name="argumentName[]"]').each(function() {
 argumentsNameArr.push( $(this).val() );
});`

Comment: A montagem está correta pelo que entendi. Só resta então debugar se o controller está recebendo corretamente a requisição.
Pode tentar usar 
@RequestParam(value = "argumentsNameArray") String[] argumentsNameArray no lugar do PathVariable